# CAS id to SMILES

Tags: molecular-structure, identification

How can I convert a list of CAS ids to structures (SMILES). I have been trying (Chemspider API, PubChem and the chemical identifier Resolver) but there are still some ids I can't find the structure. For example 166177-30-6.

Comment: I've been consistently successful with CAS' at https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/

Comment: 166177-30-6 resist to chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus for example :)

Comment: PubChem has been a great resource for looking up structure (and other) information by CAS Registry Number. My search for 138683-67-7 yields a result: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/2947 You can also search PubChem programmatically in python, for example, with just a few lines of code to retrieve the data from a list.

Comment: Yeah, PubChem seems to the most extensive. chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus may also be relying on PubChem in the background. However, 166177-30-6 is not on PubChem.

Comment: I did a Google search of 166177-30-6 and found a single hit from a German specialty synthesis company. It is possible that this CAS RN is a custom medicinal chemistry intermediate. This could explain why it does not appear in PubChem and other resources. Other than going straight to CAS, options may be limited. A full-text patent search is a possibility. At least the CAS RN provides a distinct search term.

Comment: Here's the link: https://eoschemical.blogspot.com/2019/09/eos-med-chem-kundenspezifische-synthese_698.html?m=1